# En un VPS quiero distintas versiones de php según directorio

Tags: php, apache, vps

Buenas tengo un VPS con ubuntu server 16.04 con apache tengo instalada las versiones php 7.1 y 5.6, la versión 7.1 esta última por defecto mi problema es que arrastro un proyecto de Symfony 2.8, que no quiero migrar a una versión nueva ya que es parte de un portfolio y es de muestra. Mi duda es como hacer para utilizar php5.6 en el directorio del proyecto Symfony 2.8 he buscado bastante y no me queda claro si es posible.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses docker para manejar esos escenarios, seguramente serás mas feliz, y además harás portable la configuración de tu server, eso te facilitará la vida cuando tengas que migrar...